# Why does .Average() method does not work? And error CS1061 explanation?

Tags: c#

Im trying to solve codewars.com challenge called "How good are you really?"

Description of the challenge:
There was a test in your class and you passed it. Congratulations!
But you're an ambitious person. You want to know if you're better than the average student in your class.
You receive an array with your peers' test scores. Now calculate the average and compare your score!
Return True if you're better, else False!
Note:
Your points are not included in the array of your class's points. For calculating the average point you may add your point to the given array!

My solution:

```
public class Kata
{
  public static bool BetterThanAverage(int[] ClassPoints, int YourPoints)
  {
    ClassPoints = ClassPoints.Append(YourPoints).ToArray(); // Add Yourpoints to the ClassPoints array
    int AveragePoints = ClassPoints.Average(); // Get average points
    if (YourPoints > AveragePoints) { // Compare
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Error i get:

> src/Solution.cs(5,31): error CS1061: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Append' and no accessible extension method 'Append' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> src/Solution.cs(6,37): error CS1061: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and no accessible extension method 'Average' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried to look into error code but i could not understand the explanation. What is wrong with my code, this challenge is simple, yet i cannot understand why simple method does not work?

UPDATE. SOLUTION FOUND:
Thank you all for the solutions. The code proposed by @MikeT was working and passed the tests, but it felt like im departing from the requirements.

The task im solving is in codewars.org editor and not in the Visual Studio. The task itself was predefined and i decided not to change that. But heres my new code that worked:

````
public class Kata
{
  public static bool BetterThanAverage(int[] ClassPoints, int YourPoints)
  {    
    int SumClassPoints = 0;
    int Average = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < ClassPoints.Length; i++) {
      SumClassPoints += ClassPoints[i];    
    }
    Average = (SumClassPoints + YourPoints) / (ClassPoints.Length + 1);
    if (YourPoints > Average) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```
````

Comment: The Enumerable.Average extension method is in the System.Linq namespace, which you need to add to your usings. If you are using Visual Studio it should actually propose this.

Comment: as stated in the error ClassPoints isn an int[] int[] doesn't include a function called append, if you are trying to use the Linq append function ClassPoints should be IEnumerable<int>

Comment: That's not quite right @MikeT, an `int[]` is an `IEnumerable<int>`. The issue here is the missing usings, plus the fact that `Average` doesn't return an `int`, but a `double`.

Comment: This also won't work @PetoMPP, you can't assign an `IEnumerable<int>` to an `int[]`. It's important to note that `Append` wont modify the original array (as per the code comment) but it will create an `IEnumerable<int>` that iterates over the original array first, then the appended array.

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at the start of the file.

Comment: @HenryTwist append returns an Ienumerable not an array, converting an array to an enumerable and they to an array then back to an enumerable for the average is bad practice and hence why i suggested switching to an enumerable in the parameters, pass in an array then it remains an enumerable the whole way through, this is also most likely what is blocking the IDE from suggesting that a namespace is missing

Comment: @MikeT I never said to convert the `IEnumerable` to an array. That would be redundant unless you intend to enumerate it more than once. Just a simple `double average = ClassPoints.Append(YourPoints).Average()` would do here.

Answer (score -1):

2 issues firstly you are using the wrong types and leaving the compiler to figure out the conversion and you are using extension functions that need adding to the code base

firstly the types you pass in an array, then convert it to an Ienumerable with Append, you then convert to an array and then call average which is also an Ienumerable function, also average returns a double not an int and as converting double to an int may lose data it doesn't implicitly convert and an explicit conversion is required either on AveragePoints or the output of the average function

second c#allows you to expand a classes functions from a static class that includes a method `public static MyExpander(this <class to apply to> myClass)` however if you haven't told the compiler that you are using them it doesn't know they exist, in this case the expansion fuctions are located in the System.Linq namespace so you have to use that

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Kata
{
    public static bool BetterThanAverage(IEnumerable<int> ClassPoints, int YourPoints)
    {
        ClassPoints = ClassPoints.Append(YourPoints); // Add Yourpoints to the ClassPoints array
        int AveragePoints =(int) ClassPoints.Average(); // Get average points
        if (YourPoints > AveragePoints)
        { // Compare
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in casting Average to int, you can declare AveragePoints as double

Comment: either you cast average to int or yourpoints to double for the compare, either way you can't compare int & double with out converting one of the values, so not much difference bar an explicit or implicit conversion

Comment: The cast to `int` is a bug waiting to happen, it coincidentally is the same in this case, but all it takes is changing `>` to `>=` for it to make a big difference.